# Is there a conclusive convergence test for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (e^{2/n^2}-1)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I have tried testing for convergence using the common methods but none of them were conclusive.
Wolfram Alpha tells me  $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left (e^{2/n^2}-1\right )$$ does approximately converge to 7.8597 but it gives no further explanation as to why or how. Is there a trick or some standard series that makes this solvable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mean value theorem shows that the summand is $O(n^{-2})$ so the sum converges.

Comment: $e^x-1 \sim x, x\to 0$

Comment: By Taylor's theorem with Lagrange remainder, $0 \le {\rm e}^x  - 1 \le x{\rm e}^2$ for $0\le x\le 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^{2h}-1}h=2,
$$
you have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{2/n^2}-1}{1/n^2}=2.
$$
Therefore, since the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$ converges, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(e^{2/n^2}-1\right)$ is also convergent.

Comment: just to make sure i understand correctly: because the fraction $\frac{e^{2/n^2}-1}{1/n^2}$ is finite as $n\rightarrow\infty$ and because the denominator converges as a series, the numerator must also converge as a series?

Comment: The fact that both series are series of non-negative reals is also relevant.

Answer (score 0):

When $n\to +\infty$, we have: $$e^{\frac{2}{n^2}}-1\,\,\sim\,\,\frac{2}{n^2}$$
as the asympotic $e^x-1\,\,\sim\,\, x$ when $x\to 0$ holds.

So, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(e^{\frac{2}{n^2}}-1\right)$ converge by the asynptotic test.